# Using git, how do I add a common framework (also under git) to the root directory?

Tags: git

I have a few Git Repos on GitHub like this:

- framework
- website #1
- website #2

The framework is common between `website #1` and `website #2`, and I would like to include it at the root level (bonus points if I can update it from the master framework repository).

```
|-Framework
|---Modules
```

Then, the two sites would include modules at the same level

```
|-Website (belongs to website repo)
|---Modules (belongs to Framework repo)
|---Blah (belongs to website repo)
```

Is this possible in Git? At first I looked at Submodules, but they appear to check out into their own directory, which isn't right for this particular framework (that being said, I am using a submodule of [Dave Gamache's Skeleton](https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton) in my Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to combine code from different repositories in the same directories. As you mentioned the only way is to use submodules. But each of them has to live in it's own directory.

Comment: Bugger. That'd be a nice feature to have.